# How to pass meta data about how to filter in pipe using Angular2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Consider the following

Here is my component

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'myInput',
  pipes: [myPipe],
  template: 
  `
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="name">
    <li *ngFor="#item of items | searchByTitle: searchText">
      <div>{{item.title}}</div>
    </li>
  `,
 })
```

Here is my pipe

```
@Pipe({
    name: "searchByTitle"
})
export class myPipe {

    transform(value, args: any[]) {
        return value.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(args[0]) !== -1);
    }
}
```

As we can see from the above code we are filtering the list using user inputted `searchText`, the `searchText` is the filter criteria for the title.

However if I have the following data

```
items = [{'myTitle': 'title1'}, {'myTitle': 'title2'}]
```

it would not work, I can only pass in data that have the key `title` in it, is there a way I can pass in an arbitrary key to filter by?

Such that I can do

```
return value.filter(item => item[myArbiraryKey].indexOf(args[0]) !== -1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide several parameters to your pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: "searchByTitle"
})
export class myPipe {
  transform(value, args: any[]) {
    var field = args[0];
    return value.filter(item => item[field].indexOf(args[1]) !== -1);
  }
}
```

and use it this way:

```
<li *ngFor="#item of items | searchByTitle:title:searchText">
  <div>{{item.title}}</div>
</li>
```